# On click of button why number of clicks is Not increasing (in React simple Example)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React. Making a simple example, where clicking on button changes state - should rerender children and no of clicks should get updated. But it doesn't and remain '0'. Please help, where is the problem?

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
var Home = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.btnText = "click Me"; 
    this.commentData = "No comments till now"; 
    this.clickNo = 0; 
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
        <div> 
            <ButtonComponent buttonText={this.btnText} clickNumber={this.clickNo} handleclick={this.clickHandler} /> 
            <CommentComponent commentText={this.commentData} />
        </div>
    )
  },

  clickHandler: function(){ 
    this.setState({clickNo: this.state.clickNo++});     
  }
});

var ButtonComponent = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.buttonText}{this.props.clickNumber}</button>
    )
  }
}); 

var CommentComponent = React.createClass({ 
  render: function(){
    return (
        <p>{this.props.commentText}</p>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `this.state.clickNo = 0;`?

Comment: Not sure which React tutorial you're using, but it's a hella terrible one.

Comment: Are you watching a tutorial from 2015? This is an old way of writing react components

Comment: Yes, trying to learn basics. What's problem in this code?

Comment: This is what react looks like in 2023 https://beta.reactjs.org/learn

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/@aghh1504/2-increment-and-decrease-number-onclick-react-5767b765103c) an example of Increment/Decrease number onClick React example.

Comment: @Deadpool whenever you see `var` in a JS tutorial, run away.